# Auto load options when an option is selected PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

I'm having a problem with a code I'm working on. I'm obviously new to php and mySQL.
I want to load an option field from mysql database when another option is selected.
That is to say:
I have options

```
<select name=state>
   <option value=Lagos>Lagos</option>
   <option value=Abuja>Abuja</option>
   <option value=Rivers>Rivers</option>
   </select>
```

and another set of options:

```
   <select name=City>
   <option value=Lekii>Lekki</option>
   <option value=VI>VI</option>
   <option value=Ikoyi>Ikoyi</option>
   </select>
```

I have a database called **PLACES** and tables for state and city
I want to Load a corresponding list of cities when I select state.
That is, when I select Lagos, all cities in Lagos will be populated in another drop down menu.

Please note that there are 2 Select Fields.

Please help me out, guys.

Comment: make a `ajax` request and get data from database on the basis of dropdown value.

Comment: please post the code you are working on.

Comment: As Kartikeya has mention.. ajax is your best option, but then, show us what researches you have done first!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your application architecture and preference:

You can do a ajax call to server each time to get corresponding cities based on the state selected. Please follow the post [Auto-populating Select Boxes using jQuery & AJAX](http://remysharp.com/2007/01/20/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-ajax).

**Or**

you can preload all cities based on state in a JSON format and show corresponding city based on the state selected. Please see my working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mguh8qdm/) in the Jsfiddle.

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     // you need to fill this cities value getting data from city table of your DB
cities = {
    "Lagos": ["LagosCity1", "LagosCity2"],
    "Abuja": ["AbujaCity1", "AbujaCity2", "AbujaCity3"],
    "Rivers": ["RiversCity1", "RiversCity2", "RiversCity3"]
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#state').change(function() {
       var state = $(this).val();
    if(cities[state] && cities[state].length > 0)
    $("#Scity").html('');
     $.each(cities[state], function(i, city) {
            $("<option>").attr("value", city).text(city).appendTo("#Scity");
        });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
State: <select id='state' name='state'>
   <option value=0>Select</option>
   <option value='Lagos'>Lagos</option>
   <option value='Abuja'>Abuja</option>
   <option value='Rivers'>Rivers</option>
</select>
City: <select id="Scity" name='city'></select>
</body>
</html>
```

**Or**

You can by default show all your cities in city select box and filter out cities while a state is selected and only show cities that belongs to that state, please see a kind of example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sabithpocker/fRuhn/).

Comment: Wow. This was very helpful. I'm sorry I am responding late though.

Comment: @EstheronsSamuel, Thanks, would you mind accepting the answer if it works for you and give a up vote if you finding it helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use Ajax call to get data on the basis of state selected.